# How can I include separate JS file into my Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to include a separate JS file into my Vue component but I can't figure it out. After some Googling I tried these approaches:

```
<script>
export default {
  import * as Menu from './../assets/menu/Menu.js'
}
</script>
```

And this:

```
<script>
export default {
  const Menu = require('./../assets/menu/Menu.js');
}
</script>
```

And this:

```
<script>
export * from './../assets/menu/Menu.js'
</script>
```

All without success. I just want to load the Menu javascript file into my Header.vue component.

I am using these dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "django-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "postinstall": "yarn build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.13",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.6"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@vue/app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

I am new to Vue so can someone please help me out?

Edit:

The Header.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <header>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div id="hamburger" v-on:click="display_menu()">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <img src="https://humancoders-formations.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/course/logo/104/thumb_bigger_formation-vue-js.png" alt="logo">
                <nav id="menu">
                    <li><a>Menu 1</a></li>
                    <li class="drop"><a v-on:click="display_drop_menu()">Menu 2 dropdown <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
                        <ul class="drop_menu">
                            <a>Sub menu 1</a>
                            <a>Sub menu 2</a>
                            <a>Sub menu 3</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="drop"><a v-on:click="display_drop_menu()">Menu 3 dropdown  <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
                        <ul class="drop_menu">
                            <a>Sub menu 1</a>
                            <a>Sub menu 2</a>
                            <a>Sub menu 3</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>Menu 4</a></li>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="loader" v-if="load">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div id="overlay" v-if="load"></div>
        <div id="background">
            <h3>This menu is responsive, resized on.</h3>
            <h3>The header is hide when scroll down and show when scroll up, try it !</h3>
            <button v-on:click="loaded()">Click here for loader!</button></button>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export * from './../assets/menu/Menu.js'
</script>

  <style scoped lang="scss">
    @import './../assets/menu/menu.scss';
  </style>
```

Menu.js file:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    close_all_menu();
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove("display_menu");
});
var last_scroll = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
    if(!document.getElementById("loader")){
        close_all_menu();
        var header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
        if(Math.abs(last_scroll - this.scrollY) <= 5) return;
        (this.scrollY < last_scroll) ? header.style.top = "0" : header.style.top = "-" + header.clientHeight + "px" ;
        last_scroll = this.scrollY;
    }
}
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
            load : false,
    },
    methods: {
        display_menu : function(){
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            (!body.classList.contains("display_menu")) ? body.classList.add("display_menu") : body.classList.remove("display_menu");
        },
        display_drop_menu : function(){
            var drop_menu = event.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("drop_menu")[0];
            var drop_menus = document.getElementsByClassName("drop_menu");

            Array.from(drop_menus).forEach(function(e){
                if(e != drop_menu){
                    e.classList.remove("display");
                }
            });
            var lis = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li");
            Array.from(lis).forEach(function(e){
                e.style.marginTop = 0;
            });
            (!drop_menu.classList.contains("display")) ? drop_menu.classList.add("display") : drop_menu.classList.remove("display");
            if(window.innerWidth < 660 && drop_menu.classList.contains("display")) {
                event.target.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.marginTop = drop_menu.clientHeight + "px";
            }
        },
        loaded : function(){
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflowY = "hidden";
      console.log('t');
            (this.load) ? this.load = false : this.load = true;
        }
    }
});
function close_all_menu() {
    var lis = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li");
    Array.from(lis).forEach(function(e){
        e.style.marginTop = 0;
    });
    var drop_menus = document.getElementsByClassName("drop_menu");
    Array.from(drop_menus).forEach(function(e){
        e.classList.remove("display");
    });
}
```

Comment: Put it before and outside the `export{}` at the top of the `<script>`.  You can see this being done in the second image example in the docs: [Single File Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#Introduction).

Comment: What is in Menu.js?  as @zero298 mentioned you need to put the import above the export declaration, but you also need to actually do something with it, and of course what you want to do depends on what it is.  For example it you literally just want to use the contents as the js for your component then a single line of `export * from "./../assets/menu/Menu.js"` should do it.

Comment: Actually I think this is what you mean, so I've posted it as an answer below.

Comment: I tried that but then nothing renders anymore on the webpage, its just blank. I added my Header.vue en the Menu.js code for reference

Comment: Its a snippet I found on vuejsexamples that I try to use

Comment: The code you have is designed to be a top-level app not a component (for example there can only be one `id="app"` in a webpage so this is not suitable in a component) and the js is designed to be at the top level (it has an independent reference to the `<div id="app">` element).  I strongly suggest you start by going through the vue quick start guide and work up to components through that - it won't take that long and the documentation is excellent. To give you a full answer to your question would basically mean re-describing much of what is in the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Ah yes stupid thanks will do!!!